# ASP.Net Ajax PageMethod - retain reference to DOM object

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, ajax

When calling an ASP.Net PageMethod, we call it as follows:

```
function doSomething(htmlElement)
{    
     PageMethods.GetText(onSuccess, onFailure);
}
```

What is the best way to retain a reference to the htmlElement in the above example, so that we may continue to work with it in the onsuccess method?

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact that Javascript supports [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)),  you won't need to worry about maintaining the reference to the element; since it's lexically scoped within onSuccess(assuming you're inlining an unnamed function in the place of onSuccess.)

Simply put, the function you put in for onSuccess can already use the reference to the element as if it were passed in as a parameter.

```
function doSomething(htmlElement)
{         
    PageMethods.GetText(function(x, y){ var v = htmlElement /*won't be null*/   } , onFailure);

}
```